# 301 redirect not working with ip address

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

i am working in my development server. 
It doesn't have the domain name instead i used to access it via IP address. i want to make redirect script from 
`http://11.10.11.19/index.php to http://11.10.11.19/` (ip address given is sample)

### .httaccess ( Development server )

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ 11\.10\.11\.19$ [R=301,L]
```

### .httaccess (live server)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.domainname.com [R=301,L]
```

The same thing when i tried with my **live site** and in **localhost** it is working.

Comment: Try with `http` prefix like `http://11\.10\.11\.19$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to redirect `index.php` to the root of the domain, whether you are accessing it by IP or by name.

This should do the trick in both cases:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^()index\.php$ $1 [L,R]
```